# React dynamic state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a dynamic state. But when I update it, its always override it so it's not adding a new key and value. For example :

```js
const [DynamicForm, setDynamicForm] = useState({});

<Input placeholder={element.Name}
       onChange={(e) => {
           updateDynamicForm(e.target.value, field.Id);
       }}
/>

const updateDynamicForm = (value, Id) => {
    setDynamicForm({ ...DynamicForm, [Id]: value });
    form.setFieldsValue({ [Id]: value });

};
```

I using that dynamic input like 3-4 times.

This is how I want =>

```
{15:"Input 1 Text example", 16:"Input 2 Text example"} //15 and 16 is Id that i give it on change event.
```

This is what i get =>

```
{15:"Input 1 Text example"}  //After i edit input 2 that object becomes => {16:"Input 2 Text Example"}
```

What is wrong with my codes i really confused a lot. Thanks for reply!

Comment: What is form.setFieldsValue?

Comment: @JamesAnderbard sorry I forgot about mention about it. Its coming from ant design Form component. Its for fill field in the form.

Comment: What's the output of the DynamicForm just before you update it? Try console.log of it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got experience with antdesign form and in general, you're doing it wrong (not always, but most likely). Form state **should not be external to the form**, it should be contained within the form. Once you start to externalize form state, you run into issues trying to keep your external state in sync with your actual form state under various circumstances.

In order to have a component react to changes in form state, use:

```
<Form.Item dependencies={[...names of fields}]>
 {(getFieldValue) => {
     return /* any jsx you want */
 }}
</Form.Item>
```

Your form should be wrapped in a `Form` component and each of your Inputs/Selects/Radios/whatever should be wrapped in a Form.Item